# Пользовательские структуры данных в Clojure

Tags: data-structures, производительность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли в Clojure создавать свои структуры данных? (например декартово дерево по неявному ключу)

Проигрывают ли они при этом в эффективности другим хардкорным языкам программирования (типа Си, С++ где можно оперировать данными на стеке и т.п.)?

Comment: я думаю, что Вы понимаете, что раз clojure компилятор компилирует в java байт код, то он по определению не может быть быстрее кода на С/С++. Но конечно, и на с/с++ можно написать такой код, что clojure его обгонит.

Comment: @KoVadim десятое правило Гринспена